# Android Development - Text and Edittext going opposite ways

Tags: android, xml

I don't exactly know what the issue is but just to clarify on a few things:

1. I'm using LinearLayout
2. My goal is to make a text string "example" go below an EditText view and it seems that whenever I try using margins to move the views and try to center them they always end up going the opposite way from each other, do you guys have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: please provide your layout file

Answer (score 0):

you can use Relativelayout as parent Layout and position your widgets relative to each other using their id
you can put this code in your textview xml definition

layout_below:@id/the one above it

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout

Defined `android:orientation:vertical`, allows you to position in list form each view that you add

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

RelativeLayout

Defined `android:layout_below="id_view"` where id_view is the id of the view that would go first

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_text"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```